# Image inside List takes automatic spacing issue Swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-list

I have list inside that Image and Section

```
List {
            
            Image("iosimg")
                .resizable()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .listRowBackground(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            
            Section {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(catvm.categories, id: \.id) { category in
                            
                            Button {
                                print("selected Category",category.category)
                                viewState = category.category
                            } label: {
                                CategoryView(category: category)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            }
         }
```

But when I run this simulator it shows like

How to prevent spacing around First Image and Section below that ( I want like pickup location content

[image: How to prevent spacing around First Image and Section below that ( I want like pickup location content]

Comment: You could add `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0,leading: 0,bottom: 0,trailing: 0))` to the
 `Image` and the `Section`, adjusting the values as desired.